# C# csv loaded into datatable missing columns

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, dataset

I've loaded a csv into a datatable but some of the columns are being read as blank when they're not blank. I initially posed this question only having an issue with the header, but I'm now also seeing this issue in my data rows so I need to reask... what is the problem with my dataset and why are some columns being read as a blank?

Currently, this setup will read data for columns 1-7 (I don't need 8-10). Data is populated for all columns correctly except column 4. Strangely, I have two files I've tested, both similar in structure, but one of them has values in column 4 and the other doesn't. The full code is setup to loop through many files, checking for start and end of data, then load to sql server.

Sample CSV:

```
By OrgID/Location

As of:   December 6, 2017 at 10:13 AM 

Date Range: summaryYM           2017M08 to 2017M08

"orgid=13778 medType=' '"
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col10"
13778,140242,"2A","2017M08",0,0.058,78,".",".",
13778,140242,"2B","2017M08",0,0.014,19,".",".",
13778,140242,"2C","2017M08",0,0.083,133,".",".",
13778,140242,"2ICU","2017M08",0,0.099,114,".",".",
13778,140242,"3 ICU","2017M08",0,0.076,88,".",".",
```

code

```
//open connection to csv
string connStrCsv = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited"""
      , Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
OleDbConnection connCsv = new OleDbConnection(connStrCsv);
connCsv.Open();

//store csv data in datatable
string readCsv = "select * from [" + Path.GetFileName(file) + "]";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(readCsv, connCsv);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "sheet1");
DataTable table = ds.Tables["sheet1"];
connCsv.Close();

//find header to define start of data
int start = 0;
StreamReader headerSearch = null;
int incr = 0;
headerSearch = new StreamReader(file);
while (!headerSearch.EndOfStream)
{
  incr++;
  string line = headerSearch.ReadLine();
  if (line.Contains("\"col1\",\"col2\",\"col3\",\"col4\",\"col5\",\"col6\""))
  {
      start = incr;
  }
}
headerSearch.Close();

//load each row of excel into SQL server until first empty row
string sqlConnStr = "Data Source=mysource;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
SqlConnection connSql = new SqlConnection(sqlConnStr);
connSql.Open();

int end = start;
while (table.Rows[end][0].ToString().Length != 0)
{
  string sql = string.Format
  (@"
  delete from schema.table
  where ss_col1      =  {0}    
      and ss_col2    = '{1}' 
      and ss_col3    = '{2}' 
      and ss_col4    = '{3}';

  insert into schema.table
  values ({4}        
      ,'{5}'         
      ,'{6}'         
      ,'{7}'         
      , {8}          
      ,'{9}'         
      ,'{10}'        
      ,getdate()
      ,user_name()
      ,getdate()
      ,user_name());"
      //delete statement variables
      , table.Rows[end][0].ToString()
      , table.Rows[end][2].ToString()
      , table.Rows[end][3].ToString()
      , infTypes[i]
      //insert statement variables
      , table.Rows[end][0].ToString()
      , table.Rows[end][2].ToString()
      , table.Rows[end][3].ToString()
      , infTypes[i]
      , table.Rows[end][4]
      , table.Rows[end][5].ToString()
      , table.Rows[end][6]
  );

  SqlCommand execSql = new SqlCommand(sql, connSql);
  execSql.ExecuteNonQuery();

  end++;
}
connSql.Close();
```

Comment: Find out where the “garbage” is coming from and fix that.

Comment: To check for blank columns in 4-7: `if(row[4].ToString() == "" && row[5].ToString() == "" && row[6].ToString() == "" && row[7].ToString() == "") { // then  cols 4-7 are blank }` unless I'm missing something here.  I'm not familiar with OleDB, but in this code sample, the data is actually coming from there, not from a CSV file (even if it originally came from CSV), so I would write a query to filter what you are selecting according to what you need, or use database constraints to prevent junk data from winding up there in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your responses so far, looks like I didn't explain myself clearly.
I can't just fix the garbage because the file comes from an external source that I don't have control over. And there are about 200 lines in the csv, out of which only maybe 30 have the data I need but where the 30 lines are changes with every file because the amount of garbage changes.
The blank columns I'm getting in columns 4-7 should have data in them. I need each of the columns 1-7 to match a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to load it into a datatable?
If "header1","header2","header3","header4","header5","header6" are unique would it not be easier just read the csv file until you find those?

Example...

```
StreamReader Reader = null;
string FilePath = "Your File Path";
try
{
  Reader = new StreamReader(FilePath);
  while(Reader.Peek() > 0)
  {
    string line = Reader.ReadLine();
    bool HeaderFound = false;
    if(line == "What ever your headers are")
    {
      HeaderFound = true;
    }
    if(HeaderFound)
    {
      //Here is all your data you were looking for.
     //Do whatever you need to do with it now.
    }
  }
} catch(exception e)
{/*Deal with the issues*/}
finally
{
  if(Reader != null)
  {
    Reader.Close();
    Reader.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My initial issue with the headers was resolved using the streamreader but after some changes to the csv occured, I began to see the same issue with the dataset. I am reopening the question now and hope to get a solution for the dataset adaptor.Fill technique, rather than having to redev using streamreader and split statements.

Comment: Turns out microsoft's built dataset adapter is a mystery how it works exactly which is why I was missing some columns. Therefore this streamreader option is the only way I can control and know exactly what is happening with my csv. I ended up having to use this streamreader and split option in the end - didn't turn out to be much more re-deving.